# Calculate sum of input fields

Tags: html

I've created a simple HTML5 form, with the code below.
It successfully works in Chrome in W10, as well as in Chrome on my Android Phone.

The autosum function doesn't work on an iPad in Safari, nor Chrome.

What am I missing?

Cheers,
Stewart

```
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="tta.value = parseInt(r1ta.value)+parseInt(r2ta.value)+parseInt(r3ta.value)+parseInt(r4ta.value);ttb.value = parseInt(r1tb.value)+parseInt(r2tb.value)+parseInt(r3tb.value)+parseInt(r4tb.value);te.value = parseInt(r1e.value)+parseInt(r2e.value)+parseInt(r3e.value)+parseInt(r4e.value)">
<table style="height: 97px;" width="216">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>RINK</td>
<td>TEAM A</td>
<td>TEAM B</td>
<td>ENDS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><input id="r1ta" name="r1ta" type="number" /></td>
<td><input id="r1tb" name="r1tb" type="number" /></td>
<td><input id="r1e" name="r1e" type="number" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td><input id="r2ta" name="r2ta" type="number" /></td>
<td><input id="r2tb" name="r2tb" type="number" /></td>
<td><input id="r2e" name="r2e" type="number" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td><input id="r3ta" name="r3ta" type="number" /></td>
<td><input id="r3tb" name="r3tb" type="number" /></td>
<td><input id="r3e" name="r3e" type="number" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td><input id="r4ta" name="r4ta" type="number" /></td>
<td><input id="r4tb" name="r4tb" type="number" /></td>
<td><input id="r4e" name="r4e" type="number" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>TOTAL</td>
<td><output for="r1ta r2ta r3ta r4ta" name="tta"></output></td>
<td><output for="r1tb r2tb r3tb r4tb" name="ttb"></output></td>
<td><output for="r1e r2e r3e r4e" name="te"></output></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your field's default value is not 0 it is null. so it cannot be able to sum 1 + null for ins.

Comment: Thanks for that. I updated it and tried again on the iPad, but it doesn't auto populate. Tried in Chrome & Safari